# Git best way to combine two repositories when cloning

Tags: git

lets assume I have to repositories rA and rB.

rA could look like

```
 root/
   -> myfile.c
   -> foo.c
   next_folder/
      -> bar.c
```

rB will look like

```
 root/
    -> otherfile.c
    next_folder/
        -> otherbar.c
```

Is there a way (should also be part of a git hook script for me) that allows me when someone clones rA that the process also perform a merge to rA from rB, without adding the files of rB to the next commit of rA (and in the best case: also add them to the gitignore). After cloning/checkout rA should look like

rA_withB

```
 root/
    -> myfile.c
    -> foo.c
    -> otherfile.c
    next_folder/
        -> bar.c
        -> otherbar.c
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without adding the files of rB to the next commit of rA"?

Comment: If I do a `git merge --no-commit --no-ff rB/master` this leads to the fact, that the merged files are added to be in the next commit when the user do not manually "deselect" them.

Comment: Do you understand that merging rB into rA will add the files of rA to the next commit of rB? Whether or not you use `—no-commit` or `—no-ff`

Comment: Yes I know, thats the reason why I tried to describe the problem. I want to know if, and how, this problem can be solved. I know about the "problem" of `git merge`